# New page not loading - ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

This strikes me as pretty simple, which is why it's bugging me that I can't figure it out. I am creating a basic news app in rails. I have a "Posts" controller that controls the content for my basic pages. I want to have a page with local news. I went into the posts controller and made a new action called "local"

```
def local

end
```

I then went into my routes.rb file and made a route for the page.

```
get "posts/local" => "posts#local"
```

I then created a local.html.erb file and placed it in my post views.

When I try to click a link with the posts_local_path, I get this:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound

Extracted source (around line #74):
72
73
74
75
76
77

# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_post
  @post = Post.friendly.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
```

I don't understand. This is not involved in any way with the page I am trying to open. I'm not using that part of the controller. I'm stuck. Can someone help me understand what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have `before_action` in your controller

You want to ensure that's not called for the local action

```
before_action :set_post, except: [:local]
```

or if it's only used in show

```
before_action :set_post, only: [:show]
```

You can pass either except or only arrays of the action names as symbols.

Comment: I have these before actions: before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy, :new, :create]

The page I am attempting to open is currently blank. I just want the basic, blank page to open.

Comment: In the routes is `get "posts/local" => "posts#local"` above where you presumably have `resources :posts`?  If not I think it's considering it as a call to `posts#show` with an id of local.  Which would then try to set the post hence the error

Answer (score 0):

The problem originates from the fact that you're not passing any id in the params to the controller. Hence your method set_post cannot retrieve any post and returns the ActiveRecord error.

So you've got 2 options:

- Either you want to use set_post and need to specify an :id param in your routes
- Or you avoid calling set_post by adapting your before_action filter (as per the answer of j-dexx)

Comment: Right now, I want no content on the page. I just want a blank page to open. I have to before actions: 

before_action :set_post, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy, :new, :create]

I don't think (?) either of them should impact the page as it's blank. Not sure what to do.